# Is there a way to define access policy in one place in ASP.NET Core that is similar to Spring security's antmatcher

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization

In Spring Security you can define which endpoints you want authorization on in one place like

```
http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
  .antMatchers("/**").denyAll();
```

In .NET I can create a default deny policy by adding an AuthorizationPolicy with RequireAuthenticatedUser:

```
      services.AddControllersWithViews(o =>
      {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
          .Build();
        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new endpoint))
      });
```

Is there a way to define which paths I want and don't authorization on in a similar way in .NET as in Spring Security, i.e. define it all in one place?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable authorization for a specific url, like the login page, you can add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the corresponding action.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
    }
}
```

Look at this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was probably not clear enough in my question, that I wanted a similar way as how they do it with antmatchers in Spring Security. It is easier to avoid mistakes in your access policy if you can define it in one place. I think I have found the way to do it now with RazorPage Conventions: `services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(o => {o.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/").AllowAnonymousToPage("/Home/Index");});` though I haven't got it to work yet